# Why does the ticker get stuck while using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zomjc7z/

JavaScript:

```
function init() {

            var ctx;
            var turn = [];

            var xV = [-1, 0, 1, 0];
            var yV = [0, -1, 0, 1];
            var queue = [];

            var elements = 1;
            var map = [];

            var MR = Math.random;

            var X = 5 + (MR() * (100 - 10)) | 0;
            var Y = 5 + (MR() * (30 - 10)) | 0;

            var direction = MR() * 3 | 0;

            var interval = 0;

            var score = 0;
            var inc_score = 50;

            var sum = 0,
                easy = 0;

            var i, dir;



            var win = window;
            var doc = document;

            var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
            var setInt = win.setInterval;
            var clInt = win.clearInterval;

            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                map[i] = [];
            }

            canvas.setAttribute('width', 100 * 10);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', 30 * 10);

            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var div = document.getElementById("pnlGame");
            div.appendChild(canvas);
            //doc.body.appendChild(canvas);

            function placeFood() {

                var x, y;

                do {
                    x = MR() * 100 | 0;
                    y = MR() * 30 | 0;
                } while (map[x][y]);

                map[x][y] = 1;
                ctx.strokeRect(x * 10 + 1, y * 10 + 1, 10 - 2, 10 - 2);
            }
            placeFood();


            function clock() {

                if (easy) {
                    X = (X + 100) % 100;
                    Y = (Y + 30) % 30;
                }

                --inc_score;

                if (turn.length) {
                    dir = turn.pop();
                    if ((dir % 2) !== (direction % 2)) {
                        direction = dir;
                    }
                }

                if (

                    (easy || (0 <= X && 0 <= Y && X < 100 && Y < 30))


                    && 2 !== map[X][Y]) {

                    if (1 === map[X][Y]) {
                        score += Math.max(5, inc_score);
                        inc_score = 50;
                        placeFood();
                        elements++;
                    }

                    ctx.fillRect(X * 10, Y * 10, 10 - 1, 10 - 1);
                    map[X][Y] = 2;
                    queue.unshift([X, Y]);

                    X += xV[direction];
                    Y += yV[direction];

                    if (elements < queue.length) {
                        dir = queue.pop()

                        map[dir[0]][dir[1]] = 0;
                        ctx.clearRect(dir[0] * 10, dir[1] * 10, 10, 10);
                    }

                } else if (!turn.length) {
                    if (confirm("You lost! Play again? Your Score is " + score)) {

                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300);
                        queue = [];

                        elements = 1;
                        map = [];

                        X = 5 + (MR() * (100 - 10)) | 0;
                        Y = 5 + (MR() * (30 - 10)) | 0;

                        direction = MR() * 3 | 0;

                        score = 0;
                        inc_score = 50;

                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            map[i] = [];
                        }

                        placeFood();
                    } else {
                        clInt(interval);
                        //window.location = "YourTasks.aspx";
                    }
                }

            }

            interval = setInt(clock, 120);

            doc.onkeydown = function (e) {

                var code = e.keyCode - 37;

                /*
                 * 0: left
                 * 1: up
                 * 2: right
                 * 3: down
                 **/
                if (0 <= code && code < 4 && code !== turn[0]) {
                    turn.unshift(code);
                } else if (-5 == code) {

                    if (interval) {
                        clInt(interval);
                        interval = 0;
                    } else {
                        interval = setInt(clock, 120);
                    }

                } else { // O.o
                    dir = sum + code;
                    if (dir == 44 || dir == 94 || dir == 126 || dir == 171) {
                        sum += code
                    } else if (dir === 218) easy = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

When there is no more turn left and the javascript alert is shown, the snake square get stuck and the canvas doesn't clear.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work

Comment: Everytime I enter the javascript and save the JSFiddle site just clears everything out. So I created the fiddle with HTML and CSS and JQuery and posted the JS here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the width of your canvas to 1000 (`canvas.setAttribute('width', 100 * 10);`)

where you are clearing it you are only clearing a 450 wide box

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300);
```

You need to change this to

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 300);
```

Comment: Just a quick question, I am trying to add a button which handles the "OK" from the confirm alert. I removed the canvas from the DIV and readded but it keeps appending. I would like to handle the "OK" to restart the game but from a button outside of the canvas.

Comment: if you don't mind reloading the page you can use `location.reload();`

Comment: I would like to avoid reloading the page and just start a fresh copy of the game :/

Comment: I didn't quite get what you meant by "handle the OK to restart the game but from a button outside...". Could you add stuff to the fiddle and add a comment as to what is supposed to happen. Btw if you just want to restart you could always do a clearRect and call init() again. In you init where you do `doc.createElement('canvas');` just check if canvas already exists - if it does just skip the createElement

Comment: So pretty much, if the user clicks OK, the game restarts. I would like to prevent the confirm alert which can get annoying after a while. Instead, display the score in a label and have a play button which the user can press to play the game again.

Comment: Do you want to post that as a separate question for others, if it's urgent? Otherwise i can take a shot at it tomorrow. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I can wait :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :).